# Message Queue Authentication By Certificate - C#

Tags: c#

Am working on Message Queue authentication by certificate in C#. In MQ, I have registered the internal certificate and used it my code. Please find my code snippet. When I tired to attach digital signature and sender certificate, my message is not received in MQ. Can any one help me. I have used this msdn URL for my reference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706312(v=vs.85).aspx.
Computer name is my ip address in the below code.

Code :

```
    using (MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue())
{
    messageQueue.Path = "FormatName:DIRECT = TCP:" + ComputerName + "\\PRIVATE$\\" + “Test”;                                                
    System.Messaging.Message message = new System.Messaging.Message(); 
    message.UseAuthentication = true;
    message.UseEncryption = true;
    message.EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.Rc2;

    string testMessage = "Test Sample Message";
    SHA1Managed sHA1 = new SHA1Managed();
    var hashValue = sHA1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(testMessage));
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Documents\MQCeritificate.cer");
    RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPublicKey();
    var signature = rsa.Encrypt(hashValue, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);

    message.DigitalSignature = signature;
    message.ConnectorType = Guid.NewGuid();
    message.CorrelationId = Message.Id;
    message.AppSpecific = 1;
    message.Label = "456";
    message.SenderCertificate = cert.GetRawCertData();
    message.Body = Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
    messageQueue.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Which certificate I need to use here to push the message in MQ.

Comment: I don't have experience with this, but I would set it up to receive [acknowledgement messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms707129(v=vs.85).aspx) so you get an idea about what might have gone wrong. There is a [possibly good example here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31974f4f-e26d-4d94-8aa8-991697d93e35/msmq-acknowledgments?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added acknowledgement message in administration queue. I could not get any details in the queue. For normal operations, I meant that pushing messges in MQ, am getting acknowledgement messages. For this scenario, am not receiving acknowledgement messages